# Does tangent function have some special procedure for solution or properties?

Tags: trigonometry

I have found that $tan(222.32)$ gives us 0.910, but $tan^{-1}(0.910)$ gives us 42.42 back. Which have not any symmetry or 90 or 180 sum or difference relationship.
Then what is it?

Comment: $222.32-42.42=179.9$. $180$?

Comment: Looks like round-off error to me, as well.